# How can i define an array antenna(three non co-linear antennas) in ns2?

Tags: ns2

How can i define an array antenna(three non co-linear antennas) in ns2? I need this for time difference of arrival based localization in sensor networks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please post your ns2 code so we can see what you have tried so far?

Comment: dear if i had tried it, my question would have had the code already and the question would have been very different....i m new to ns2....just know how to define antenna...but don't know how to define antenna array..